# Ruby backreference in gsub is not working properly

Tags: ruby, regex

I am confused with the following result,

I have a string like this:-

```
string = "hai\"hello\!tst\`\~end"
```

When I use space between backslash and back-reference (\1) it is working fine as expected.

```
puts string.gsub(/([\"\!\`\~])/,'\\ \1')
=> hai\ "hello\ !tst\ `\ ~end
```

But the same thing is not working without space! The string is replaced with the backreference number.

```
puts string.gsub(/([\"\!\`\~])/,'\\\1')
=> hai\1hello\1tst\1\1end
```

But I am expecting answer like

```
=> hai\"hello\!tst\`\~end
```

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using character classes, you don't have to escape your characters: just write ["!`~].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is more backslashes:

```
string = "hai\"hello\!tst\`\~end"

puts string.gsub(/([\"\!\`\~])/,'\\\\\1')
# >> hai\"hello\!tst\`\~end
```

Two-step processing is performed on the secont argument of `gsub`, so that `\\\1` becomes `\\1` becomes literal `\1`. With five backslashes first four of them are reduced to one, and `\1` escape sequence is intact and available for replacing.

Comment: Can you give some more description why we need more backslashes? of course it is working :)